# Python 2.7: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, csv, int, bubble-sort

I am trying to open a csv file and convert the values from strings to integers so I can sort the list. The results I received were:

"[[], ['190'], ['200'], ['250'], ['350'], ['90']]".

Here is my original code.

```
import csv

def bubbleSort(scores):
    for length in range(len(scores)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(length):
            if scores[i]>scores[i+1]:
                temp = scores[i]
                scores[i] = scores[i+1]
                scores[i+1] = temp


with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    scores = list(r)


bubbleSort(scores)
print(scores)
```

I tried adding in the line :

```
scores_int = [int(score[0]) for score in scores]
```

Now however I am recieving the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Here is the current version of code I am working with:

```
import csv

def bubbleSort(scores):
    for length in range(len(scores)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(length):
            if scores[i]>scores[i+1]:
                temp = scores[i]
                scores[i] = scores[i+1]
                scores[i+1] = temp


with open ("rec_Scores.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    scores = list(r)
    scores_int = [int(score[0]) for score in scores]


bubbleSort(scores_int)
print(scores_int)
```

If anyone could help me with my current problem it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working (python 2.7) if the csv file contain numbers line by line as:

```
 190
 200
 250
 350
 90
```

Comment: But it did not sort the numbers